# How to pass multiple arguments to function in function in Python?

Tags: python, function, multiple-arguments

I have a function in first Python file to do some manipulation with two strings:

```
J = "aA"
S = "aAAbbbb"

def numJewelsInStones(self, J: str, S: str) -> int:
    return len(J + S)
```

And function in another file to check time taken (performance test for small expressions):

```
def check_time(function, *args):
    print(timeit.timeit(lambda: function(args)))
```

So on startap i get error in `print(timeit.timeit(lambda: function(args)))`:

```
rating.check_time(solution.numJewelsInStones, J, S)
TypeError: numJewelsInStones() missing 1 required positional argument: 'S'
```

How can i pass multiple arguments to inner function?

Comment: You need to unpack the arguments in your call to `function`, like so: `function(*args)`. +1 for the use of type hints, are you taking a course using them? If so, and if you don't mind, where?

Comment: @N.Wouda thanks! It is work! I just needed to add one star before `args`. it's task from **leetcode**. Right now i did [that](https://leetcode.com/problems/jewels-and-stones/).

Comment: Very nice how they're now using type hints!